# How do i access a specific variable from another js file, based on conditions from my current js file?

Tags: javascript, variables

```js
function tidsbestilling() {
  var valgtDato = document.getElementById('datepicker').value
  console.log(valgtDato)
  var getDato = "D" + valgtDato.substring(0, 2) + valgtDato.substring(3, 5) + valgtDato.substring(6, 10)
  console.log(getDato);
}
console.log(D31102019);
```

Im trying to access a const called D31102019 from another js file. The variable is date specific, so if the user chooses another date(ex. 30-10-2019), i want to be accessing the variable D30102019 instead. How can i make the "getDato" variable(currently defined as "D31102019"), into something i can actually use to access the const from the other file?

Comment: I think you are talking about vanilla Javascript. In that case, if you are declaring the variable globally and loading the same file first, then you should have that variable available in all the other javascript files.

Comment: It is avaliable. When i do console.log(D31102019) the array shows up like it should. But when i do console.log(getDato), it just logs D31102019 in the console. I want to access the array in the variable D31102019, like i do in the first log.

Comment: It's because, the variable `getDato` holds the string value `"D31102019"` and not the variable `D31102019`. You should replace `console.log(getDato)` with `console.log(window[getDato])`. This should get you the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a global variable it will be in the scope of window, you can access it using:

```
var variableName = 'D31102019';
window[variableName];
```

Or in your case

```
window[tidsbestilling()]
```

But you have to return the result from your function:

```
function tidsbestilling() {
  var valgtDato = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
  var getDato = "D" + valgtDato.substring(0, 2) + valgtDato.substring(3, 5) + valgtDato.substring(6, 10);
  return getDato;
}
```

> This declaration creates a constant whose scope can be either global
>   or local to the block in which it is declared. **Global constants do not
>   become properties of the window object, unlike var variables**. An
>   initializer for a constant is required; that is, you must specify its
>   value in the same statement in which it's declared (which makes sense,
>   given that it can't be changed later)

If you choose using `const` which comes in the next version of javascript then you are supposed to export the constant from one file and then import that constant whereever you require using es6 module system. If you go with es5 then `var` is fine. But it is always a good idea to make your code modular avoiding globals.

Comment: It is a global variable since its being logged just fine in the last line of my code snippet, but window doesnt seem to work. When i try to log window[tidsbestilling()] it shows as undefined in the chrome console. When i try to log just tidsbestilling(), it gives me D31102019

Comment: Figured it out, as soon as i changed D31102019 from a const to a var, it started working. Any idea why it wouldnt accept a const?